# Bash scripting: Skipping files and grep

Tags: linux, bash, grep

Bash scripting is not my strongest point. I have a file structured as

```
% comment
filename1 pattern-to-search1
filename1 pattern-to-search2
...
```

I would like to write a script to grep `filename` for `pattern-to-mat` for all for every line in the file.

So far I have

```
while read file p
do
    if [ "${file:0:1}" != "%" ]
    then
    grep -o "$p" $file | wc -l
    fi
done
echo -e "\nDone."
```

But it doesn't skip the files starting with `%`. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see anything in your script that would cause the problem you describe. Are you sure the problem is what you think it is?

Comment: Tell you the truth, no. But I did like @sehe's answer... looks pretty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd simply do

```
grep -v '^%' | while read file p
do
    grep -c "$p" -- "$file"
done
```

That way, the comment lines won't even *reach* the `read` loop

Comment: While you're at it, you might as well change `-o` to `-c` and drop the `| wc -l`. (Also, `--` would not go amiss.)

Comment: I didn't even read that far. It isn't essential to the question :)

Comment: Well, *nothing* in your answer is essential to the question, so far as I can tell. Your script doesn't seem to fix any problems with the OP's script.

Comment: Also, one difference between your script and the OP's is that the OP's will also skip lines that start with whitespace+`%`, whereas yours requires the `%` to be the very first character. I don't know if that's a problem.